# How do I get Power Armor training in Fallout New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I've found some power armor, but I can't use it yet without training. I assumed that the Brotherhood of Steel would train me, if they like me enough.

I've completed the Brotherhood of Steel quest series for the overseer (the original one, I did not overthrow him), but I did not get any Power Armor training. What do I have to do to be able to wear Power Armor?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Power Armor Training in FO:NV is available at the end of a few different quest chains in order to provide access for a variety of paths.

**From the Brotherhood:** After completing *Eyesight to the Blind* or *Still in the Dark*, wait 24 hours for the lockdown to end, and the Elder will offer you PA:Training, whether McNamara, or Hardin. (Hardin may ask you to go blow up the Silver Rush before offering training.)

Alternately, you can complete Arcade Gannon's follower quest, *For Auld Lang Syne* -  in addition to rewarding you with the unique Tesla Power Armor, you'll receive the necessary training to use it.

Comment: I did not went back 24 hours later, I just noticed the elder did not talk to me anymore. I'll have to check that out.

Comment: When I went back I got another quest from the Elder and after that finally my power armor. The waiting for the end of the lockdown is critical, I totally missed that and thought the quest line is over.

Answer (score 3):

After the lockdown is complete the elder will give you a quest called "Eyesight in the Dark".  Complete this mission and earn your place amongst the Brotherhood of Steel.  Oh, and for the record, you dont have to side with Hardin.  I ignored Hardin for the most part.  I told him i'd see what i could do but then never interviewed the other Paladins until after the mission for the components was finished and then i only interviewed one of them.  I waited like 6 days before the lockdown was over and nothing. Then I zoned out to LT 1 and then zoned back in and voilà.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The only other option that allows the player to get the power armor perk exists on the pc by adding it via the console command:

> player.addperk 58fdf

or

> SetPCCanUsePowerArmor 1

[source](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Power_Armor_Training)

Note you'll have to restart your game after using the console if you wish to earn achievements.