# Get Power Armor Training without  the Brotherhood of Steel?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get Power Armor training in Fallout New Vegas?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9801/how-do-i-get-power-armor-training-in-fallout-new-vegas)

I blew up the Brotherhood of Steel in the  Hidden Valley chapter with the self destruct sequence and had my companion carry out tons of power armor. Is there any other way of getting power armor training with the Brotherhood eliminated?

Comment: I don't play Fallout, so I wouldn't know, but is your question not answered [by this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9801/how-to-get-power-armor-training-in-fallout-new-vegas/9851#9851)? "Alternately, you can complete Arcade Gannon's follower quest, For Auld Lang Syne - in addition to rewarding you with the unique Tesla Power Armor, you'll receive the necessary training to use it."

Answer (score 7):

You can get the Power Armor Training by doing the companion quest "For Old Lang Syne" from Arcade Gannon. [See this answer for more information on how to trigger the companion quests](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10799/initiating-companion-quests-in-fallout-new-vegas/10806#10806).

Answer (score 1):

In the quest Where you get the remenants power armor and the gannon family tesla armor (power armor) which are the best armor types in the game. the enclave remnants, in the remnants bunker (near jacobstown) Can offer you power armor training.

requirements are:
have arcade gannons tally system positive (visit silver rush, crashed vertibird etc.)
follow either yesman, mr house or ncr. leigon are excludedfrom this oppotunity.
For more info visit:

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/For_Auld_Lang_Syne

This is the quest to get this. it can be easily and permenantly blocked through wrong actions in the game, so make constant saves.

Answer (score 1):

The companion quest of Arcade Gannon " For old Lang Syne" will give you the training plus a free set of remnant power armor. You can also get the Gannon tesla power armor if you convince Arcade not to join the fight at the Hoover dam. The downside of this quest is the event wont happen until you killed Mr. House being an independent power or with NCR... If you have a good relationship with the NCR early on the game ( liked or idolized) talk to Col. Hsu and he'll give you key to NCR safehouse where you can have a power armor that requires no training plus the mercenery ranger armor and helmet.